# How to recover deleted files in ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, data-recovery, delete

I am using kubuntu 13.04 and accidentally I have deleted My important .pdf files by pressing shift+delete. It was in the home directory. Is there any way by which I could recover them back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Shut your system down. Now.

2 Boot it from a [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/) Live CD or USB.

3 Image the hard drive with  [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to another drive.

4 Then, use [PhotoRec](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/storage/8257-how-to-recover-lost-files-after-you-accidentally-wipe-your-hard-drive) or [TestDisk](http://www.linux.org/threads/undelete-files-on-linux-systems.4316/) on the imaged drive to recove the files

5 Lastly, start making good backups (Lesson Learned!)